# Bitrise | how to print the report after test automation

Tags: user-interface, automation, report, bitrise

I have run the test automation and got the result in the logs -

> Execution failed for task ':uitest:android_test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///bitrise/src/emv_ui_automation/uitest/build/reports/tests/android_test/index.html

and i have set up the workflow (deploy to Export test results to Test Reports add-on)  with the attached configurations as Test result search pattern:

```
   */emv_ui_automation/uitest/build/reports/tests/android_test/*
```

but still the test report is not generated properly

Comment: Hi, following this. As I am facing same issue, after reading all the docs and trying all the combination, I resorted to simple Unit Test step that is already available and used default reports.